# Consequences of overstaying Schengen visa in Switzerland

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, overstaying

I overstayed my Schengen visa by 2 weeks when I traveled to Switzerland. The police in Switzerland gave me a paper saying that I will receive a penalty order in one or two months requiring me to pay a fine and that I may also be issued a prohibition of entry forbidding me from entering Switzerland and the Schengen states for a period of one or more years.

I am holding a Vietnamese Passport. This occurred today, and I am worrying about what will happen to me.

Does anyone know how much is the fine for overstaying a Schengen visa?  Will I not be allowed to enter the Schengen states?

Comment: Moral of the story: don't overstay your visa!

Comment: How did they possibly find out or notice ???!!

Comment: Hey I had the same thing happen to me. I am very concerned right now. I was wondering if you had paid the fee at the airport? If so, did you get the extra penalty order after 1-2 months as well? Was there a fee then? Could you tell me your experience, please. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Fattie when Switzerland first joined the Schengen area, they were very diligent about looking for entry stamps as people were leaving.  They almost fined my wife once because she hadn't gotten a stamp on our previous entry (by land).  I don't know if they're still as diligent, but I suspect they are.

Comment: Last year when I was leaving Switzerland, a lady in the passport line next to mine was being given the same warning.

Answer (score 10):

[There is a blog entry on VagabondJourney about similar problem.](http://www.vagabondjourney.com/penalties-fines-overstaying-shengen-visa/) And then [another entry I found on Lonely Planet.](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1841750)

According to Schengen rules, you need to leave Schengen area for at least 90 days, before you can enter again for 90 days.

As many people on above mentioned sites comment, "your mileage may vary". As I understand, you were not deported from Switzerland, but if you are still inside of Schengen, you may have more problems when you try to cross the border again. Some people advise to leave through a country, where control is less strict in order to avoid prohibition of entry.

As to fines, I don't know if there is one rule, but people reported that they were fined anywhere between 550 and 1100 €.