# What's the most cost-effective destination for a four night trip from Berlin to a non-Schengen destination?

Tags: budget, europe, schengen, destinations, itineraries

To avoid overstaying my visa, I need to leave the Schengen area for three full days (four nights). What's the most cost-effective way to do this from Berlin, Germany.

Here are the requirements:

- Start and end in Berlin
- Direct flights only
- Must not depart Berlin before 18 May
- Must return to Berlin no later than 30 June

Nice to have:

- The trip should occur over a weekend
- Shorter travel time is better
- Non-UK destination

Comment: First off if your are concerned about overstaying your Schengen, likely, short stay visa 4 days elsewhere won't help you.  Your best bet would be former Yugoslavia or Bulgaria.  But the question as it stands is not constructive since there are too many possibilities but we have no idea on your restrictions

Comment: With what citizenship? That can affect the cost and difficulty of obtaining a visa for your short excursion.

Comment: @Karlson With all these criteria, the choice becomes very small ...

Comment: @MarcelC. Choice is not small.  You in your answer listed 9 countries on top of this you might want to review one of OPs older questions: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13482/what-are-the-consequences-of-a-us-citizen-overstaying-a-schengen-visa which indicates he's a US citizen but even if we don't make this assumption.  Unless he's under a long stay visa, which needs to be clarified this leave and reenter won't work because it's 90 days in any 180 day period, so unless OP is planning 3 months stay the solution won't work.

Comment: I have added some clarification to my answer.

Comment: I'm currently in the Schengen zone and I have a flight to leave that will put me at 93 days in the zone. Leaving for four nights will bring me under the limit of 90 days in a 180 day period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Berlin, the closest non Schengen destination is the [Kaliningrad Oblast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaliningrad_Oblast). The beeline distance is +- 500 kilometers and over the road its +- 600 kilometers. There are direct flights between Berlin and Kaliningrad. It is just one hour.

Otherwise, there are a couple of places in non Schengen countries that you can reach in more or less 2h30 by plane: Sofia (Bulgaria), Bucharest (Romania), Belgrade (Serbia) and Zagreb (Croatia). So as to find the most cost effective option, I would play a bit with [Matrix Airfare Search](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/search.htm) or a similar tool.

In 2 hours you can also reach Kiev (Ukraine) or Minsk (Belarus) from Berlin. However prices for direct flights to these destinations are much higher than for the other destinations mentioned.

Depending on your citizenship, all these destinations may not be visa free. And a visa may not be obtained for free. Take that into account.

Comment: And Schengen visa you're trying not to overstay may not allow you to return....

Comment: You're welcme. Good choice. It's an interesting place

Answer (score 3):

Kaliningrad is a good option in that case:

Book a direct flight from Air Berlin: http://www.airberlin.com/

<strike>And get a 72 hour russian visa at the airport: http://www.konigsberg.ru/eng/kaliningrad/express-visa.htm</strike>

UPD: Only citizens of Shengen countries, UK and Japan have a possibility to get express visa, so only regular tourist visa is required for the US citizen.

Comment: Hi Nick, I think this is a good answer but do you mind elaborating a little more on why you think Kaliningrad meets all the requirements in the questions? Thank you and welcome to Travel.SE!