# Overstay in Schengen

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I am an American who studied at a Latvian university in the previous fall semester.  I had planned to stay almost an academic year, so the company that organized my trip and partnered with the university in Latvia told me that I needn't worry about the 90 day limit, that they would register me for a temporary residence permit so that I could stay in Latvia longer than 90 days.  Despite the fact that I gave them all the documentation they requested for this, they apparently forgot to do it.  Anyway, I left Latvia to spend time in Moscow during the winter holiday and, naturally, was denied re-entry on the basis that I had already significantly overstayed.  I wasn't fined at the Latvian border.  The border guard simply told me I would be able to return if I stayed away for 90 days, no penalty, just a warning and a document explaining the 90/180 day rule.

I currently have tickets to fly back to America on May 3rd from Moscow to Riga and then Frankfurt.  I entered Schengen August 28th and left for Russia January 12th.  I was denied re-entry February 7th.  Does the entry refusal affect the 180 day period in some way?  Am I at risk of a fine for the overstay if someone notices in, say, Frankfurt?

Comment: The more important question is whether someone notices in Riga.  If so, you may be unable to fly to Frankfurt.

Comment: Well, no one checked/stamped my passport in Riga when I entered.  I figured it would be more likely that I'll either not be allowed to fly to Riga from Moscow in the first place, or there will be a problem in Frankfurt when I'm leaving Europe altogether.

Comment: Well by my calculation you're fine as far as the 90/180 rule goes. Feb 7th doesn't count because you never entered. The potential problem is that you might be denied entry by border officials because of your previous overstay.  Were you given any documents when you were denied entry?  If so, what did they say? (Edit your question to add the information.)  If you're denied entry, that will happen after you land in Riga, and the airline will most likely have to transport you back to Moscow.

Comment: Also, were you denied entry because you overstayed (i.e., because you broke the rules), or because of the 90/180 rule (i.e., because you had already used up your 90 days in the previous 180)?

Comment: I was denied because I had already used up my 90 days in the previous 180. The document they gave me doesn't really say anything more than that, an explanation of why I was denied and my signature with the signature of the guard.  In fact, the border guard told me to just go through Belarus and Lithuania if I wanted to get back in illegally.

Comment: Then it sounds like you wont have a record (see for example http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/13697/19400) as the guard was sympathetic. It then boils down to whether the German guard can fine you for a previous overstay. (If they do their job correctly, they'll see the previous overstay because the latter part of it counts in the 90/180 calculation on your travel date.) That's a good question; I hope someone who knows the answer will post.

Comment: Jay, reminder for next time. You are responsible to register your address and get your residence permit yourself. It takes about an hour for Americans to get a residence permit from most European countries. As phoog mentioned, check out that link and you will have an idea of the consequences. I would suggest contacting the University (they will refuse all the blame, in most scenerios)