# Entry restrictions for Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I have finally received my Schengen visa from the Czech Republic embassy in Dubai. But I have received the visa only with 12 days entry where I have applied for a multi entry visa.

They have made the validity as same as my itinerary dates. 
I have changed my mind and am planning to enter Bulgaria first, then Czech Republic and finally The Netherlands. Can anyone suggest whether it will be a good choice?

Is there any possibility of being held during any of these entries?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you cannot enter Bulgaria with a single-entry Schengen visa.  You will need a separate visa from Bulgaria.

Comment: Dear sir.... Thanks for your reply... Can you please confirm whether i can enter bulgaria with schengan visa???

Comment: Can you confirm whether your visa is a single-entry visa?  If it is, you cannot use it to enter Bulgaria.

Comment: Yes.. It is a single entry visa

Comment: Hii sir...   Can u tell me what will be the consequence if i exit the schengan area one day late after the visa expiry

Comment: See [What are the consequences of a US citizen overstaying a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13482/19400)  As the accepted answer makes clear, the fact that the question asks about US citizens is irrelevant; the potential consequences apply to anyone who has stayed too long.

Answer (score 2):

For the Bulgarian visa, see the comment by phoog.

Your Schengen visa has a **duration of stay**, a **validity period**, and a **number of entries**.

- The duration determines how many days you can stay in the Schengen area. Partial days count full.
- The validity period determines when you can stay in the Schengen zone. Unless there was a mistake, the validity should be as long or longer than the duration.
- The number of entries determines how often you can enter *the Schengen area*.

For a first-time application, it is typical to limit the duration to the itinerary, and to give at most a few extra days of validity to adjust the itinerary.

With a Schengen visa you can make minor changes to your itinerary, as long as you stay within the duration and validity. You may not lie about your itinerary, and you should avoid the *appearance* that you lied even if you make legitimate changes.

It would look bad if you enter the Czech Republic and *immediately* travel on to the Netherlands, because if that had been your plan all along you should have asked the Netherlands for a visa. If you spend several days in the Czech Republic it looks better.

So when you enter the Czech Republic, you should bring documentation that you have been in Bulgaria and how you will travel on and leave the Schengen area. When you travel from the Czech Republic to the Netherlands, there will be no systematic immigration checks (and no passport stamp), but there may be a random spot check. If that happens, you should have documentation that you have been in the Czech Republic and how you will leave the Schengen area.