# Schengen visa 1 day longer than duration

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

I was in budapest for a conference. The visa duration said 10 days however i missed my flight and i left the schengen area on the 11th day, i didn’t even know it was an issue as my visa validity was longer than my intended stay by 2 weeks . I had no problems at the airport however i read here that staying more than the written duration is a huge problem. I need to take another schengen visa for my PhD studies and i dont know if this will affect it or not? And if yes, what can i do? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The consequences of an overstay can range from nothing through to deportation. [What are the consequences of a US citizen overstaying a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13482/what-are-the-consequences-of-a-us-citizen-overstaying-a-schengen-visa) There’s nothing you can do other than to explain the reason why you missed your flight, ideally providing evidence to prove it was unintentional.