# Spain schengen overstay

Tags: schengen, overstaying, chilean-citizens

My friend is from Chile and overstayed their Schengen visa in Spain by a few months.

I've read that the consequences of overstay can vary quite a bit across EU countries. Is there any information out there about how Spain specifically would treat her?

If she is has a ticket to fly to a non-EU country, say Morocco, would she be allowed to do so? Or would they likely deport her back to Chile (plus maybe fine her etc). 
My thinking was that if she has the ticket to exit the EU, they might not care so much as long as she leaves.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I couldn’t find an official source on overstaying fines for Spain. If she’s leaving voluntarily it’s highly unlikely she’d be prevented from doing so in favour of deportation. As you’ve already discovered, the likely penalties include a fine and an entry ban. She’ll also have to disclose the overstay in any future visa application that asks for this information,and the overstay could make it harder to avail herself of visa-free entry privileges https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13482/what-are-the-consequences-of-a-us-citizen-overstaying-a-schengen-visa

Comment: I'm wondering, what is she intending to do in Morocco? If it's just a matter of spending a few days and then trying to come back to Spain (or elsewhere in the Schengen Area), that's definitely not a good plan. Also she should probably allow for ample time to go through passport control, as it may take longer than usual to process her.

Answer (score 4):

It depends a lot on her luck, and on the person handling her.

If she's leaving, odds are they will let her continue their travel to Morocco, as they only want you out and don't care where you go to. On the other hand, she will probably be banned for entering the Schengen area for a few years.

Comment: I guess there’s a chance Moroccan Immigration could deny her entry if they spot the overstay and conclude she’ll likely do the same there, and/or if she can’t prove eg means of subsistence and valid medical insurance for her stay.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems hard to get anything definite really. Like this will come down to chance in the end.